# Fix UnboundLocalError: local variable 'click' referenced before assignment error in python/pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, syntax-error

**pls help me solve this error : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'click' referenced before assignment**
I'm new to pygame & I am learning to code a game using pygame. I am trying to creating a home menu for my game which contains two buttons : play_button & stats_button. Play button will run the game() function which is yet to coded.Stats button will show the leaderboard & other stuff. but, its not going as expected. When i click the first red button (play button), its still on the home screen & no response. The same with stats button. Also, the "X" does not close the game window now. Plus, an error adds to my problem now !

**CODE :**

```
#importing area
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------\

#switching on
pygame.init()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------\

#on screen area
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("space.io")
icon_game = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Uv Pygame\code\ufo.png") #load icon, r is compulsory
pygame.display.set_icon(icon_game)
background_1 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Uv Pygame\code\bg.jpg")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------\

#essentials
run = True
game = False
stats = False
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
click = False

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------\

#time
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\

#core

def game():
        game = True
        while game:
                screen.fill((255,255,255))
                draw_text("GAME" ,font,(0,0,0) , screen , 195,80)
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                                        game = False
def stats():
        stats = True
        while stats:
                screen.fill((255,255,255))
                draw_text("STATS" ,font,(0,0,0) , screen , 195,80)
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                                        stats = False
                
        
def draw_text(text, font , color, surface, x, y):
        textobj = font.render(text, 1,color)
        textrect = textobj.get_rect()
        textrect.topleft = (x,y)
        surface.blit(textobj,textrect)
        

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------\        

def main_menu():
        while run:
                screen.fill((255,255,255))
                draw_text("HOME" ,font,(0,0,0) , screen , 195,80)
                        
                play_button  = pygame.Rect(210,200,180,50)
                stats_button  = pygame.Rect(210,300,180,50)
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), play_button)
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), stats_button)
                
                mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                
                if play_button.collidepoint((mx,my)):
                        if click:
                                game()
                if stats_button.collidepoint((mx,my)):
                        if click:
                                stats()
                        
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == QUIT:
                                pygame.quit()
                                sys.exit()
                        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                                if event.button == 1:
                                        click = True

                        
                pygame.display.update()
                           
main_menu()
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Uv Pygame\code\pract_1.py", line 95, in <module>
    main_menu()
  File "C:\Uv Pygame\code\pract_1.py", line 78, in main_menu
    if click:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'click' referenced before assignment
```

**Pls tell me why am I getting this error & how to solve it "THE SIMPLEST WAY"***

Comment: You write `if click:`in  the function `main_menu()` and then assign click to True in that same function. It does not know you are trying to use `click` in the `# essentials` section. Are you only going to use click in the `main_menu()` function or are you going to utilize it somewhere else?

Comment: I am going to call that function as follows :
1. when player wants to return to home from game
2. when player wants to return to home from stats 
3. initially, the player will be on the main menu when code runs

is that all you need to know ??

Can you pls help me out ?